# linux virtual dedicated hosted server recommendation?

Tags: virtualization, hosted

Any recommendation? I want to have linux virtual hosted server for my apps..

## Thnks a lot..

Comment: Already voted as argumentative...

Answer (score 0):

Go for it.

Just check out your software RAM/CPU/broadband/HDD requirements and see what your local providers can offer you. It's not too expensive.

For recommendations, ask at your local Linux or web developers community, because I think it's a region specific thing.

Before starting, make sure you are fine with ssh and command line file system browsing, file operations, text editor, distribution specific file system hierarchy, reading and understanding log files. Get ready to read a lot of manuals. Make sure your provider offers some backup service (mine offers recovery from daily snapshots two weeks deep) in case you screw things up.

Take care of security measures e.g. do not store unencrypted passwords, do not run open relay and such. Make sure your applications work the way you expect them to and you can fix them if they're broken before actually starting using them.

It's a lot of fun, so, once again, if you want one - go get it.

Comment: @RG: thnks for your tips..